# email, login, logout authentication problem

Tags: python, css, django, django-forms, django-templates

i want to make if user enter same username of other user than show error same as email and login function how to add email authentication...not username and please check my logout function it is right or wrong.Thank you

1. List item

   i want to check username is already exists than show error same as email and please check, my login i want to enter email not username what can i do. my logout function is it right or wrong please tell me.

List item

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib import auth

from .models import *


def appofimage(request):
    cats = category.objects.all()
    images = post.objects.all()
    data = {'images': images, 'cats': cats}
    return render(request, 'home.html', data)


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username1 = request.POST['username']
        firstname1 = request.POST['firstname']
        lastname1 = request.POST['lastname']
        email1 = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']

        # check for error messages

        # username should be under 15 characters
        if len(username1) > 15:
            messages.error(request, "Username must be under 15 characters")
            return redirect('appofimage')

        # password should match
        if password != password1:
            messages.error(request, 'Password do not match')
            return redirect('appofimage')

        # username should be alphanumeric mens does not contain any &*()%$ etc..
        if not username1.isalnum():
            messages.error(request, 'Username Should Only Contain Letters And Numbers')
            return redirect('appofimage')

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username=username1, email=email1, password=password)
        myuser.first_name = firstname1
        myuser.last_name = lastname1
        myuser.save()
        messages.success(request, 'user has been created')
        return redirect('appofimage')

    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html')


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username1 = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username1, password=password1)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f"welcome {username1}")
            return redirect('appofimage')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "not valid")
            return redirect('appofimage')

    return render(request, 'login.html')


def logout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        messages.error(request, "Try again")
        return redirect('appofimage')

    else:
        auth.logout(request)
        messages.success(request, "logout successful")
        return redirect('appofimage')
```

> signup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>SignUp</title>
  </head>
  <body>




            <div class="container-md">

                <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username">
              </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname">
              </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
              </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password1">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password1" id="password1">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>


            </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> login.html

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>Login</title>
      </head>
      <body>
    
    
    
            <div class="container-md">
                  <form action="" method="post">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                      </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
    
            </div>
    
    
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: where's your category url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create your category urls in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('/category/<int:pk>/', views.your_category_view, name="category"),
    ...
]
```

Then, your posts and your categories are linked together via a ForeignKey in your models. You need to use this in your loop to get the right category for each image. Currently you are calling `{{cat.pk}}` without looping over the cats and without linking it to the right image. I would replace your images loop (confusing way to call it btw since images is actually posts) with this:

```
{% for i in images %}
    <div class="card">
        <a href="{% url 'category' i.cat.pk %}">
            <img src="/media/{{i.image}}" class="card-img-top img-fluid" width=auto" height="auto" alt="{{i.cat.cat_title}}"/>
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you mean this <div id="/category/{{cat.pk}}"> <img src="/media/{{i.image}}" class="card-img-top img-fluid" width=auto" height="auto" alt="{{cat.cat_title}}"> </div>

Comment: No. I thought your categories were on the same page as your images. In your urlpatterns you don't have the category one, so you can't have a link like `"/category/{{cat.pk}}"`

Comment: I edited my post to match with your structure @rushabhgediya

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to solved above (authentication) problem. i will change some code.

Comment: Please don't change questions that were already answered, create a new one. It can help people in the future

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

- add a view that gives the posts of a particular category. example url will be /category/<pk>
- use the html

```html
<a href="/category/{{post.cat.pk}}">
    <img src="{{post.image.url}}">
</a>
```